# Cannot read property 'id' of undefined - REACT JS

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing

I have most of the test running correctly, but based on the test, my match props seems wrong. I have 3 other props and they are all passing.

Here is what i have so far:
`EditUser.test.js`

```
describe('EditUser', () => {

let tree;
let baseProps;
let mockmatch = {
    params: {
        id:{
            URLParams: "test edit user and add user"
        },
        type: "test",
    }
};

beforeEach(() => {
    baseProps = { 
        match: mockmatch 
 }
})

it (' Should render without a mockmatch props',() => {
  baseProps = {
  ...baseProps,
 match: {},  
 };
     tree = renderer.create(<EditUser {...baseProps } />)
     let treeJson = tree.toJSON(); 
     expect(treeJson).toMatchSnapshot(); 
     tree.unmount() 
  });
```

`EditUser.js` :
this is the location of the error, right under `render()`

```
render() {
let URLParams = this.props.match.params;
let title = URLParams.id ? 'Edit User' : 'Add User';
let type = URLParams.type;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `match` is an empty `{}` when you assigned an updated value to `baseProps` inside your `it` block.

```
baseProps = {...baseProps, match: {} };
```

Which means it doesn't contain the `params` object when you accessed it here:

`let URLParams = this.props.match.params;`

> And that is why it's throwing that error when you tried to access `id`
>   since `URLParams` is `undefined`.

---

There's two ways to solve this.

**Solution #1**

In your test, instead of assigning an empty object to `match`, you can give it a value of an empty `params`.

```
baseProps = {...baseProps, match: { params: {} } };
```

**Solution #2**

Or you can assign a fallback value `URLParams` when you're getting the value from props which in this case will be an empty object.

`let URLParams = this.props.match.params || {};`

Comment: Thanks. I am new to unit testing but I put the value and the test passed all with all of the props.

Comment: I just ran into a similar problem in another file :  this.props.services.Dashboard.URL , that means when i do baseProps =  {..baseProps,services { dashboard: {} } }; right ?    Would you recommend mocking props for unit testing and see what renders based on snapshot ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Mind the different casing of `Dashboard` and `dashboard`, I forgot but I think it might cause some issue.

Comment: "Would you recommend mocking props for unit testing and see what renders based on snapshot ?" IMO, using a consistent mocked props is important especially if you are snapshot testing cause you are sure that it's not your data that was changed but it's your component if it ever fails.

Comment: it caused the same problem, i included Dashboard value and it worked. Thanks . I think i will be able to fix  some previous tests based on your previous answers. thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186717/discussion-between-user91-and-ana-liza-pandac).